# Selecting parents and first child elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select all of an elements parents and their first child, and also the original element itself.  Here's an example of the markup:

```html
<ul id="end-here">
  <li>
    <a href="/path">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="select-me">
    <a class="select-me" href="/path">Another link</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/path">Submenu link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="select-me">
        <a class="select-me" id="start-here" class="change-me" href="/path">Another submenu link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So starting from $('#start-here') I want all the $('.select-me') stopping at $('#end-here')

I've got this so far

```js
$('#start-here').add($('#start-here').parentsUntil('#end-here', 'li, a'))
```

However this misses out the a tag child, as they are not direct parents of the original element. So the following element above isn't included:

```html
<a class="select-me" href="/path">Another link</a>
```

Comment: `$('#start-here').andSelf().parentsUntil('#end-here').find('.select_me');`

Comment: I've added the 'select-me' class just to identify the elements in the markup.  In reality there is no such class to match against.

Comment: You do realize that `select-me` isn't always the first child in its parent. So how do you want it?

Comment: maybe this will work http://jsfiddle.net/rCKZw/

Answer (score 3):

Your example code doesn't match up with what you are asking for, "select all of an elements parents and their first child, and also the original element itself". This is how the example code should look:

```
<ul id="end-here">
  <li class="select-me">
    <a href="/path">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="select-me" href="/path">Another link</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="select-me">
        <a href="/path">Submenu link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="select-me" id="start-here" class="change-me" href="/path">Another submenu link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>​
```

And the jQuery selector:

```
$("#start-here").parentsUntil("#end-here").andSelf().map(function(){
    return $(this).parent().children()[0];
});
```

The above returns the four elements that in the example have the `select-me` class.

However, if your example code is correct, the selection process cannot be as generic or flexible and you will have to specify some element types:

```
var elems = $("#start-here").parentsUntil("#end-here", "li");
elems.add(elems.children("a"));
```

Thanks to [Stano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422309/stano) for the above solution.

Comment: I don't think that markup is right.  I wanted to select the parents of the element, as well as their first child.  You've just selected the first child.  I've got it working like this: $("#start-here").parentsUntil('#end-here','li').andSelf().children('a') The only thing it doesn't add is the first child of the #end-here

Comment: Then the second solution should do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think it should be something like:

```
$('#start-here').add($('#start-here').andSelf().parentsUntil('#end-here', 'li, a')).andSelf().children().first();
```

Comment: Why answer with untested code? This will fail by just looking at `.first`. That will "Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set."

Comment: I thought the `.andSelf()` would keep the parents, but it's confusing. If this doesn't work as is, I figured the OP might be able to adjust it to get it working. From his code, it looks like he's not as clueless as some posters, so he doesn't need the whole thing written for him.